# Excel Javascript API - Sharing

Tags: excel, office-js

(Desktop version) I'm new to using the javascript API for excel, but is it possible to create an excel add-in and share with other users without having to add the add-in to an app source etc? Can it be embedded in the excel file etc. I'd like to share scripts with other users the same way that I can share VBA if it's possible?

Answer (score 3):

for security reasons as well as to make manageability of your add-ins easier, we do not store the code within the workbook, like VBA.  Instead, the javascript is hosted on your website and we have a reference to your add-in saved in the workbook.

What this means, is to get a similar experience to VBA, you must either have the add-in hosted on app source (which will make it accessible via the Office Store), OR each user in an organization must have the add-in deployed or available to them (here we recommend centralized deployment as it will give the most robust experience).

This has all the current deployment options you can use for Office add-ins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

thanks!